# Scanner not taking input when use "try {} catch (Exception e) {}"

Tags: java

For some reason when I use `try` and catch with this scanner it instantly jumps to the `catch` without even taking the input within `try {}`

This code is supposed to check if the input happens to be a different type other than int

I seemed to have forgotten to clarify that the code works when I remove the `try` and `catch`

```
int mapsehen;
try {
    mapsehen = scanner.nextInt();
    if (mapsehen == 1) {
        DrawMap();

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong.");

}
```

Comment: is the DrawMap() a static function?

Comment: And also did u import scanner

Comment: consider logging and reading what exception is caught, instead of trying to guess.

Comment: Can you show how you define ```scanner```?

Comment: *"... probably a really dumb mistake... "* - These are your real mistakes:  1) `catch (Exception e) {` - Mistake.  Don't do this. Catch the exception(s) that you are expecting, not all exceptions.  2) `System.out.println("Something went wrong.");` - Mistake.  You are throwing away all information about the exception that occurred.  So you (and others) are left to guess what it was.  Print the stacktrace or log the exception.

Comment: Q: How do you know what exceptions to expect? A: Primarily by reading the javadocs for the methods that you are calling.  In this case, the javadoc for `readInt` tells you.  (I will leave finding the javadocs for `Scanner` and reading them as an exercise ... for you.)

Comment: *the code works when i remove the try and catch*....really?

Comment: concerning your last edit, please read 
[**How should we treat posts that are vandalized by their original authors?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106812/251777)

Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, 

under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
```